# Stop ExtJs styling elements

Tags: css, extjs, styles

If i I remove say

```
height:200
```

from my ExtJs panel and add a css class in its place

```
cls: "someclass"
```

My height property in my css class is overided because Extjs still puts in a style on the element for e.g. but with minimal value (2-4 px)

```
<div class="someclass" stlye="height:2px"></div>
```

Any idea how to stop that?

Thanks

---

**Solution**

using

```
bodyCls: "someclass"
```

is stronger than

```
cls: "someclass"
```

use bodyCls in your panel and set your css to the following:

```
.x-panel .someclass {
    //css stuff in here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ext 3 you can use `autoHeight: true` in your config object to prevent Ext JS controlling it.  See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-autoHeight for the docs.

For Ext 4 there doesn't seem to be an equivalent property, there is a discussion about this on the Ext forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133148-autoHeight-feature.

However in this case if you leave the `height` parameter out and add `bodyCls : "someClass"` to the config object, you can set the height using a css rule like: `.someClass: { height: 200px; }`.

Comment: Edit - sorry I meant to put what it there now! The property needs to be `true` not `false`!

Comment: sorry but still no luck... it just overwrites it every time.

Comment: Have you set the `height` property?  If so try removing that, if that doesn't work then I'm not sure why not!

Comment: My panel is very
 minimal this.mypanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
          
          cls: "my-panel",
                autoScroll:true,
                
            });

Comment: Is that Ext 4 then?  The `autoHeight` property is not in the docs for Ext 4, so not sure if it's still there.  I can only suggest trying `height: "auto"` in that case; although I've not tested it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6823/discussion-between-mark-rhodes-and-stevanicus)

Comment: thanks for your help... very helpful indeed! Your new edit with bodyCls worked!

Answer (score 1):

Found it on a the Sencha [forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?50361-Applying-CSS-to-panel-body&p=240163&viewfull=1#post240163)

```
.someclass .x-panel-body {
     height:600px;
}
```

dont ask me why :)